# how to listen dropdown value in another component in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, dropdown, onchange

i am newbie in react. i have a dropdown which gives me different language to select which i want to share to my all components but i couldn't do it.
so far i have tried localStorage and Context but whenever i change the value i cannot see the change in my App.js.

here's my Component

```
const RTL = () => {
const handleLanguageAction = lang => {
     console.log(lang , 'language')
   };

  return (
    <OptionsButton
  list={portalLanguages}
  float="right"
  helper="Please select any language"
  label="Language"
  action={handleLanguageAction}
    />
 );
};
```

here is my app.js

```
const App = ({ role }) => {
return (
<MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={MomentUtils}>
    <SnackbarProvider>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div dir={DIR}>
          <Layout>
            <RouteFactory routes={RouteComponents} config={routesConfig} role={role} />
          </Layout>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </SnackbarProvider>
  </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
</MuiThemeProvider>
 );
};
```

i want app.js to listen the value change in dropdown function and also should presist the value even i refresh the page.
can someone help me? thanks

Comment: What is `action `?

Comment: @MarkC. onClick function

Comment: this is when you want to use `redux` or `context api` that react provides. otherwise you would have to use some event bus.

Comment: @SpiritOfDragon how can i detect the change in context api then?

Comment: if you want to persist the value on page refresh, you have to use localstorage.

Comment: @O.o yeah but how to listen to localStorage in any component when value changes?

Comment: this is what redux does

Comment: O Mukhtareya... en dasdy nanu paiye....

Comment: @UsmanSaleem you have to learn `redux` or `context api` for the basic first. there is something called dispatching an action, which you would do inside your `handleLanguageAction` function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a customEvent to communicate between RTL and App

**RTL**

```
const myEvent = new CustomEvent('language', { detail: { lang } });
document.body.dispatchEvent(myEvent);
```

**App.js**

```
document.body.addEventListener("language", (event) => {
  console.log(event.detail);
});
```